# written query in asp.net c# .......Error in join expression. Unable to parse query text

Tags: c#

```
SELECT od.pname,od.price,od.qty,od.amount,o.amount
FROM orderdetails od
 INNER JOIN order o
ON o.orderid=od.orderid
```

> Error in join expression. Unable to parse query text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"order" is SQL keyword, which should be escaped (rather - not used to name table/fields/etc).

For T-SQL:

```
INNER JOIN [order] o
```

Comment: or INNER JOIN dbo.order o